# symfony 1.4 with multiple developers

Tags: svn, project-management, symfony-1.4

I'm looking for some advice on how to setup symfony 1.4 to be used in a "multi-developer environment".

We are currently three developers working on the same project.

We've been thinking of setting up the site on a local server and then publish (deploy) our respective versions to this one regularly. In addition to this use Subversion to keep our copies in sync. The "during development testing" will be done on our local computers, with a local symfony installation on each of them.

Do this setup sound good? Are there any drawbacks? Any suggestions of better setups? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds Ok for me.

Just a suggestion: you could use a [Continuous Integration environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) such as [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to have you code automatically deployed on your testing sever after each commit in SVN or every night (or whatever you want :) ).

Answer (score 2):

We are two developers on one Symfony project.

We have several copies of project (develop, stage and production).

Besides, each of us have his own local copy with common DB with develop version.
When one of us doing push into git repository, CI environment ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) pulls changes, builds project, doing tests (phpunit), checkstyles, documentation, other tasks and if it success then deploys on develop server and doing Selenium tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my company do this all days, we use subversion, each developers have a local copy of the project, while the project is in develop, we make checkout in our test server.